# Google drive limit number of download

Tags: download, limit, google-drive-api

I have obtain the download url via webContentLink (https://docs.google.com/a/onwardsct.com/uc?id=0ByvXJAlpPqQPYWNqY0V3MGs0Ujg&export=download)

During testing, I try to download 28 times (testing) the same 24mb file using 3 different Google accounts that is allow to access the file

On the 29th time, it fail with the below message

> Sorry, you can't view or download this file at this time.

> Too many users have viewed or downloaded this file recently. Please try accessing the file again later. If the file you are trying to access is particularly large or is shared with many people, it may take up to 24 hours to be able to view or download the file. If you still can't access a file after 24 hours, contact your domain administrator.

However I still can download using the same URL if I'm login as the content owner of the document.

Anyone any idea how to overcome or there is a limit impose by Google drive on number of download permissible for any single file in a day.

Simon

Comment: Google have these limitations to minimize abuse, of course they don't mention it anywhere. This is quite common occurrence, i'm pretty sure you can't do anything about it.

Comment: Of course it should be mentioned somewhere, given that this would not be abuse in lots of other setups, such as if I use Amazon S3. Making the terms of an agreement secret means the customers are only willing to pay a fraction of the real value of a service.

Comment: I had the same problem, so I made a **JSON file in Google Drive** but the URL file (.mp3) **is in Dropbox**. It is working fantastic my friend even though I have *40,000 active* user. You can try it! Have a nice work and code day! P.S. If you need more information about my JSON FILE and How to make the URL File from Dropbox, I would like to share you everything!

Comment: Do tell, Cristofer.

Answer (score 10):

**Sorry, you can't view or download this file at this time is an error message that you may get when you try to download files on Google Drive.**

Bandwidth limits

```
Limit                          Per hour            Per day
Download via web client        750 MB              1250 MB
Upload via web client          300 MB              500 MB
```

The explanation for the error message is simple: while users are free to share files publicly, or with a large number of users, quotas are in effect that limit availability.

If too many users view or download a file, it may be locked for a 24 hour period before the quota is reset. The period that a file is locked may be shorter according to Google.

If a file is particularly popular, it may take days or even longer before you manage to download it to your computer or place it on your Drive storage.

**It could be a solution**:

1. Locate the "uc" part of the address, and replace it with "open", so
   that the beginning of the URL reads * https:// drive.google.com/open?*
2. Load the address again once you have replaced uc with open in the
   address.
3. This loads a new screen with controls at the top.
4. Click on the "add to my drive" icon at the top right.
5. Click on "add to my drive" again to open your Google Drive storage in a new tab in the browser.
6. You should see the locked file on your drive now.
7. Select it with a right-click, and then the "make a copy" option from the menu.

   8.Select the copy of the file with a right-click, and there download to download the file to your local system.

Basically, what this does is create a copy of the file on your own Drive account. Since you are the owner of the copied file, you may download it to your local system this way.

Please note that this works only if you are signed in to a Google Account. Also note that you are the owner of the copied file and will be held responsible for policy violations or other issues linked to the file.

**Another option is:**
Any public folder in Drive can host files and provide direct links to the files.

How to create the hosting URL:
https:// googledrive.com/host/**FolderID**  (your id file)

This will provide a folder that will give direct links to files inside the folder.
Note: hosting view will not display files created in Google Docs.

**My solution:**

I had the same problem, so I made a **JSON file in Google Drive** but the URL file (.mp3) **is in Dropbox**. It is working fantastic even though I have *40,000 active* user. I used this solution because I did not have time to search too much!
 I wrote you the Dropbox Limits anyway but I did not get problems with it

**Traffic limits** DROPBOX

Links and file requests are automatically banned if they generate unusually large amounts of traffic.

Dropbox Basic (free) accounts:

20 GB per day: The total amount of traffic that all of your links and file requests combined can generate without getting banned
100,000 downloads per day: The total number of downloads that all of your links combined can generate

Dropbox Plus and Business accounts:
About 200 GB per day: The total amount of traffic that all of your links and file requests combined can generate without getting banned
There's no daily limit to the number of downloads that your links can generate
If your account hits our limit, we'll send a message to the email address registered to your account. Your links will be temporarily disabled, and anyone who tries to access them will see an error page instead of your files.

P.S. If you need more information about my files and how did it and How to make the URL File from Dropbox, I hope help to the people is reading this! (*I posted it before but Someone deleted my last post*)!

Comment: Can you show your "JSON file in Google Drive" content?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like that this limitation can be avoided if you use the following URL pattern:

```
https://googledrive.com/host/file-id
```

For your case the download URL will look like this - https://googledrive.com/host/0ByvXJAlpPqQPYWNqY0V3MGs0Ujg

Please keep in mind that this method works only if file is shared with "Public on the web" option.

Comment: Do we have any confirmation of this anywhere? I need to host some files for an app that I'm about to update. On update day I reckon there will be about 100GB of downloads. I'm wondering if hosting on Google Drive is an option.

Comment: @WillCalderwood I was using Google Drive for a couple of years but had to move to [Amazon S3 cloud](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) as it's more stable service for frequent usage in comparison with Google Drive. I would suggest you to try it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I've got an App Engine back end too which should be pretty reliable, but that's 33% more expensive than the S3 cloud. I'll mirror across multiple services and get the app to try them in order of cost.

Comment: As of August 31, 2016, this is no longer an option (Google has disabled the ability to share files in this manner): https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2881970?hl=en

Comment: 2022 - This doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

**To download the file in a shell environment:**
I saw this in my error message, so I used the browser headers to assume role of a signed in account.

> You may still be able to access the file from the browser:

To download:

1. Open the file url on Browser
2. Open network monitoring tab (`Inspect Element > Networks`)
3. Attempt to download the file (you can cancel download in the browser if it starts). This step will initiate a GET network call with path `/download?id=xxxx`
4. Right click on it to copy it as a curl command for your shell
   [image]
5. Download it in your shell by redirecting the curl commands output to your file

```
{CURL COMMAND YOU COPIED} > filename
```

Answer (score -1):

This limit is indeed not specified, however their [TOS](http://www.google.com/policies/terms/) mentions that: 
"FOR EXAMPLE, WE DON’T MAKE ANY COMMITMENTS ABOUT THE CONTENT WITHIN THE SERVICES, THE SPECIFIC FUNCTIONS OF THE SERVICES, OR THEIR RELIABILITY, **AVAILABILITY**, OR ABILITY TO MEET YOUR NEEDS. WE PROVIDE THE SERVICES “AS IS”. "

This means to me that the download limit is calculated based on a set of factors that describe the user and is subject to change from one to another.

Maybe using the TOR network may help you do your job.