# Google Drive hosting downloading limit?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm hosting the files for my app on Google Drive and it downloads them right after first launch. Everything is going fine but after I released new app version, the download counts are increasing and files are becoming unavailable for some reasons. Though I did not change anything.

Is there any downloading count limit or quota?

UPDATE: i've tried to open hosting folder (link in folder properties) and get error 403 on first file downloading attempt. After i deleteed/uploaded it again the problem was fixed

UPDATE2: this happened again though nothing was changed. I think this is related to download count for sure

Comment: Did you find an alternative solution?

Comment: After that i've faced with the same problem so it seems to be limitation for sure. I've chosen paid hosting

Comment: Hey @4ntoine i will be very thankful if you could provide more info such as what hosting did you chose instead, what your app size is and on what download count Google Drive starts rejecting downloads. It will be very helpful to community. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Google does not specify any bandwidth limits, or at least I could not find any. But I think  google does have some fair usage limits in play and these limitations would be to reduce abuse of the service and again google does not mention it any where, so there might be some other factors that google considers.

Here is another [stack overflow question regarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856102/google-drive-limit-number-of-donwload) this.

While I was googling for this issue, I found [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/drive/qcbDorj-vYE/Kdu-Z0jCVe4J) forum that discussed the google drive bandwidth issue and found a [screenshot](https://09517033375839581908.googlegroups.com/attach/7f1e543fb14a5514/bug.png?part=2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrEzlUIi-cp-_lllexuzVuo5W3i_hRogSVo3BV6O-dr44Z54CaGhUmENO7U4-Y-Jnq46UIrj5Wg9itT1PlvadSAZjouEAQImtswCd9V2YLVH5iLduTY). So if this screenshot is correct then there must be some limits in placed.

[image]

Comment: can anybody say what is downloading limit?

Answer (score 4):

You should not use Google Drive as cloud storage for an app because it's not reliable.  You can get a 24-hour ban on a file if the file gets downloaded too many times. And they don't specify the bandwidth limits. It's a gray area.

Look for services such as Dropbox or Amazon S3 instead.

Answer (score 3):

google does have bandwidth limitations, by which your account is held to certain standards. overage against these limits can cause a temporary suspension of your account, typically no longer than 24 hrs, as per their FAQ. ---> https://support.google.com/a/answer/1071518?hl=en

Comment: your link discusses gmail bandwidth limit. not google drive limits.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DRing https://forum.rclone.org/t/what-is-the-maximum-download-quota-for-an-unlimited-google-drive-account-per-day/155/13

- 10TB down per day
- 750GB up per day

Comment: If this is for paid accounts, I wonder what the limits are for free Google Drive accounts.

Answer (score 0):

750GB up per day according to googles website. I assume that 1TB down must be accurate.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2490100?hl=en

Storage --> What are the Drive storage and file size limits?

Answer (score -1):

There are no banwidth limits as far as Google Drive is concerned

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/qcbDorj-vYE

Comment: There must be a limit.