# How can I properly download a file using Google Drive API?

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-client

**I'm having issues trying to get the download link of a file using Google Drive API. It says the following:**

```json
thrown in ...\google-api\src\Http\REST.php on line 134

Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Service\Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

## Function:

```php
/**
 * Downloads a file using its URL
 * @param  string $fileId
 * @return string link to download the file.
 */
public function downloadFileDriveServer(string $fileId) {
    $this->setPermissionPublic($fileId);

    /**
     * @var \Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile $file
     */
    $file = $this->service->files->get(
        $fileId, 
        array('fields' => 'webContentLink')
    );
    
    return $file->getWebContentLink();
}
```

## Inner function:

```php
/**
 * Tries to set the file permissions to public.
 * @param  string $fileId id of the file.
 * @return void 
 */
private function setPermissionPublic(string $fileId) {
    $permission = new \Google\Service\Drive\Permission();
    $permission->setRole('reader');
    $permission->setType('anyone');
    $this->service->permissions->create($fileId, $permission);
}
```

How it's beeing called:

```php
echo $fileController->downloadFileDriveServer($fileId);
```

What I've tried:
Change the local and the cloud scopes.

My local *(in code)* Scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`.

```php
const SCOPE = \Google\Service\Drive::DRIVE;
```

Inside Google Cloud console, I have basically every scope of Google Drive like:

- ./auth/drive
- ./auth/drive.metadata
- ./auth/drive.metadata.readonly
- ./auth/drive.readonly

The project is internal use only and it's working for listing files, creating directories and deleting files.

Might be relevant:
I'm not using frameworks and I've seen some questions right here and I don't understand yet where to use a:

```php
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId?alt=media
```

I know what a GET is, but don't know where to use this "GET" line above.

Any support to enable my files to be downloaded would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `don't know where to use this "GET" line`... It's a URL (without the GET bit - that's just HTTP protocol syntax), so you can embed it in a hyperlink in a web page, or use it in a cURL request, or anything else you normally do with a URL. Visiting the URL should trigger the download, if all the permissions are set correctly..

Comment: Even without the URL, you can also use the Drive API client to initiate a download too, as per https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#php

Comment: And https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-downloads#download_blob_file_content_in_a_browser talks about what you can do with the webContenLink URL, too.

Comment: If I understood the earlier part of your post though, it seems the call to `$file->getWebContentLink();` is returning that 403 error? Is that correct? If so then I think it means that whatever identity you're using to access the Drive API doesn't have permission to generate a download link for the requested file.

Comment: @ADyson >$file-`getWebContentLink(); is returning that 403 error? Is that correct?` Yes, ADyson. This is the case! The thing is... I can  create, delete, move to trash and list files in the directory. But when operating with downloading stuff, `403` happens... I've tried a lot of things like changing the scopes and can't find where the error is... I'm using `getWebContentLink()` because this processing happens in their server. When using `$response->getBody()->getContents();` (link you provided), the main processing happens in my server, right? I'm still learning so some stuff are confusing

Comment: `the main processing happens in my server, right?` I say that because I would then have to open that metadata and put inside a file in my server. When using `getWebContentLink()`` the client can diretly download the file.

Comment: `$response->getBody()->getContents(); (link you provided), the main processing happens in my server,`....yes, but `I would then have to open that metadata and put inside a file in my server`...not necessarily. You could just echo it directly to the output, without saving it. It still involves using memory and CPU on your server, though. This could be a problem if you have large files to download, and/or a lot of users.

Comment: @ADyson I'll have more than 5000 users and a lot of files, It must happen in their side, so the best way I found using their documentation is `getWebContentLink()` for binary files and `files->export()` for workspace files

Comment: If you have that many users, this sounds like it is not a suitable use case for Google Drive anyway, to be honest. It's not designed to be used as a (free) public filesharing server. Check the TOS. Even if you succeed in generating public URLs to your documents, the number of downloads will be significantly rate-limited, so you may find many files are inaccessible for periods of time, due to having been downloaded via the public link too many times in a short period. Perhaps some cloud-based file or blob storage would be a more appropriate architectural choice for your project.

Comment: (If you were sharing files on a large scale within the Drive ecosystem, where everyone is a signed up Google Drive / Google Workspace user, that might be a bit different, but the scale of _public, unauthenticated_ sharing you can do is deliberately restricted by design). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897335/google-drive-hosting-downloading-limit and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856102/google-drive-limit-number-of-download

Comment: @ADyson I see your point. It's working with my pesonal Google Drive, but with my organization's Drive I'm having this issue with permissions... And users will only make requests to the API in order to download a file, all the things will be on our server. I think it won't be that expensive

Comment: `users will only make requests to the API in order to download a file`...but that's the opposite of what you said before. Before, you were trying to set the permissions to "anyone", and get a web content link to give to someone, so they could download the file directly from Drive without going through your server. If a few users download a few large files in a short time from a public sharing link, if they exceed the quota limit then all public downloads from your account will be suspended for 24hrs. That doesn't sound like something you would want to happen.

Comment: @ADyson Didn't know that... I was trying to make the file public, generate the download link, and then after a while make the file private again (idk how, I'm trying that now)

Comment: `Didn't know that`...It's mentioned in the links I provided above. Making the link private again after some time might not necessarily prevent that, if enough simultaneous downloads happen anyway. Obviously I don't know the overall purpose of your application or what it's supposed to do in all the details, but if you're doing a public or semi-public file download service on behalf of an organisation, you probably should do it properly with some cloud-based storage designed for the purpose.

Comment: I see your point... I see what I'll do.

Comment: As a troubleshooting, in your function `setPermissionPublic` for creating permission, the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` scope is required as per the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/create#authorization-scopes) and looking at your listed scope you're using on your post, it is not there. Can you check if that scope has already been included?

Comment: Hi, @SputnikDrunk2. Yes, it was included in my project.. I have `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` scope

Comment: ...that's a different scope

Comment: Isn't that a "super" scope? That give's me access to everything

Comment: How about using `/drive.file` just for the sake of troubleshooting?

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2  `/drive.file => https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file` `"See, edit, create, and delete only the specific Google Drive files you use with this app."`I need all files